# Ubuntu 20.04 Intel 3618ngw WiFi intermittent in Asrock DeskMini A300

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

Wifi is very intermittent, I get a good connection and can ping google.com no problem but when trying to load a webpage I only get data downloading for 1 second (data rate is KB/s) every 10 seconds. I have tried the common fixes i.e. https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/ but to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try these steps? https://askubuntu.com/questions/452933/intel-centrino-slow-speed-14-04/453026#453026  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, just tried these steps and it hasn't seemed to help

Comment: We'd like to see the results of the wireless script: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Here it is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wMv7T2MYhV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your paste, we see:

```
[ 1297.828975] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Queue 10 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [1, 38] HW [1, 38] FH TRB=0x0c010a010
[ 1297.829052] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[ 1297.829188] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1297.829193] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[ 1297.829197] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode
```

And the errors just get worse from there.

Let's rename the relevent firmware file by backing it up, reboot and see if an earlier firmware version works properly. From the terminal:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode  iwlwifi-3168-29.bak
```

Reboot and let us see:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

As the result may be lengthy, please give us a paste link as above.

We also notice that there are two access points named VM4147169 and I wonder if your wifi is roaming and therefore dropping and reconnecting among the two.

One is the 2.4 gHz segment and the other is the 5 gHz segment of, I assume, the same router. I am quite confident that you have told Network Manager to connect automagically to VM4147169 when available and that your dropping is the wireless device hopping from one instance of VM4147169 to the other, always looking for a better connection, sort of like my ex-girlfriend!

I suggest that you rename one or both to prevent this. Perhaps VM4147169-2.4 and VM4147169-5.

If this is a router over which you haven't any administrative priveleges, then bind your wireless to the 5 gHz segment like this: [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: Thank you! It seems much happier now. I have renamed the network SSIDs as suggested and dmesg only showed the error that it couldn't find the latest driver

Comment: The WiFi failed again yesterday - downgrading the kernel to 5.3.18-050318-generic seems to have fixed the problem so I suspect it may be this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1846016.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance - what is the best way to request the fix for the bug is backported to newer kernels, or will I need to do it myself?

Comment: The last post on that bug suggests that the bug is fixed. Is it a kernel bug or a firmware bug? Is it specific to non-default kernels only? Why do you need a kernel version either ahead or behind the standard 20.04 version; at this time 5.4.0-45? Is the fault still present if you reboot into 5.4.0-45?

Comment: Apologies for the delay - I just tried booting in to 5.4.0-45-generic, 5.4.0-47-generic and 5.3.18-050318-generic. dmesg | grep iwl returns the microcode error for the two 5.4.0 kernels but not for the 5.3.18 kernel. The error for the 5.4.0-45 kernel is pasted here https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YrpcKM8Q2w/